# font-awesome icons not loading on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, font-awesome

I am using font-awesome icons through ejs, and I can see the icons in my localhost, but not when I push to Heroku...

I have them used like this:

```
<li>
     <a class="header-menu-tab" href="/report"><span class="icon fontawesome-star-empty scnd-font-color"></span>REPORT</a>
</li>
```

I also installed it via cli using `npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`... still nothing. any advice?

working perfect on localhost, but not on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all"
```

in **app/javascript/packs/application.js**

I had the same problem, it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Rails 6.1

Try this

At first, we need to install `yarn`.

Then let’s first install font awesome via yarn

```
$ yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

And import font-awesome stylesheets and javascripts into your application list this:

```
// application.scss
$fa-font-path: '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims';
```

and

```
// application.js
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";
```

Now, you can see to be applied icons to your site.